# How to upload a 10 mb file in Android?

Tags: android, retrofit

I have created a program in Android using file chooser I have chooses a file than after it, I have uploaded to my server everything working fine.

But I want to upload only 10mb file or want a simple program if my file size is more than 10mb file can't chooses or uploaded in Android.

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode == PICK_FILE_REQUEST){
                if(data == null){
                    //no data present
                    return;
                }


                Uri selectedFileUri = data.getData();
                selectedFilePath = FilePath.getPath(getActivity(),selectedFileUri);

                Log.i(TAG,"Selected File Path:" + selectedFilePath);

                if(selectedFilePath != null && !selectedFilePath.equals("")){
                    tvFileName.setText(selectedFilePath);

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Cannot upload file to server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }




    // Uploading Image/Video
    private void uploadFile() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Uploading File...", true);


        // Map is used to multipart the file using okhttp3.RequestBody
        Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
        File file = new File(selectedFilePath);
        String name=tv_name.getText().toString();
        String email=tv_email.getText().toString();
        // Parsing any Media type file
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
        RequestBody requestBody1=RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),name);
        RequestBody requestBody2=RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),email);
        map.put("file\"; filename=\"" + selectedFilePath + "\"", requestBody);
        map.put("name\"; username=\"" + name+ "\"", requestBody1 );
        map.put("email\"; email=\"" + email+ "\"", requestBody2 );
```

Comment: You really should have searched a bit more rather than just put up a question. Variations of this question have been asked a lot.

Comment: Yes sir. I have search and used file.length but in my coding where have i put it..

Comment: The word Urgent is not well seen here! It is like you want to put pressure on others by saying that and often results in downvotes. Just wanted to mention that for the future.

Comment: Sorry Sir, for my Urgent Word..

Comment: I need Another Help when i upload more 500 kb file or image the file or images is uploaded but my dialog bar is not dismiss.. Please help me Sir,

Answer (score 0):

You can use File [length()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length()) to get the file size in bytes and have a conditional to check if its over 10mb.

example

```
long maxLength = 10000000;
File file = .....;

if(file.length() > maxLength){
    //failed length validation
}else{
    //continue
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to do it. I have used file.length but i don't know where to put it.

Comment: Is that's more helpful?

Comment: Thank You sir For Your Time :) I'll try to integrate your code with my uploadFile() method.. Thank You So much..

Comment: Thank You,,,,,,, :) :) :) :)  "Frogger Sir"

Comment: I need Another Help when i upload more 500 kb file or image the file or images is uploaded but my dialog bar is not dismiss.. Please help me Sir,